# test object can't see libraries called by script under test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm testing a script that mainly consists of an object `Foo`, which imports a library `bar`.

```
import bar

class Foo():
    *do stuff*

f = Foo()
*do stuff*
```

Now I create a unittest class to test Foo.

```
import foo

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = foo.Foo()
    
    *do tests*
```

Later, it has a line like:

```
bar.method(...)
```

This fails with 'bar not defined', but shouldn't it be imported via `import foo`? How do automatically load whatever is required by the script under test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importer model indeed imports everything from the other file, but under the imported model name as a namespace. See an example:

`so_imported.py`

```
import json

class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.text = "A phrase"
```

`so_import.py`

```
import so_imported

class Test2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.inner = {"test": so_imported.Test().text}
        print(so_imported.json.dumps(self.inner))

Test2()
```

So you see the `json` library imported under the module's namespace ?

If you want to import everything from the imported file without any namespaces, you can use: `from foo import *`. Then the objects will be merged into the importer namespace.